# Cythonize ends with 'fatal error C1002: compiler is out of heap space in pass 2'

Tags: cython, cythonize

I try to cythonize a .py script. It is a PyQt5 gui with a large number of QToolButtons, and a working EventFilter. The c module is built successfully, however, the compilation fails with the following error:

> d:\stuff\mapform2a.c(11338) : fatal error C1002: compiler is out of heap space in pass 2
> LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe' failed with exit status 1257

The compiler comes from Visual Studio 2019. Python 3.5.5 (yes, old, I know, but I have reasons...).

**Is there any way to increase the heap space when trying to "cythonize -i script.py" ?**

Cython documentation is really not clear on this (for a non-C-expert at least...)

**EDIT**
The full log is as follows:

> C:\temp\MapForm>python setup.py build_ext --inplace Compiling
> MapForm2A.py because it changed. [1/1] Cythonizing MapForm2A.py
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File:
> C:\temp\MapForm\MapForm2A.py   tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd,
> full_module_name) running build_ext building 'MapForm2A' extension
> creating build creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5 creating
> build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL
> /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" /TcMapForm2A.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\MapForm2A.obj MapForm2A.c creating
> C:\temp\MapForm\build\lib.win-amd64-3.5 C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo
> /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO
> /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64
> "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64"
> /EXPORT:PyInit_MapForm2A
> build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\MapForm2A.obj
> /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MapForm2A.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
> /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\MapForm2A.cp35-win_amd64.lib
> MapForm2A.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_MapForm2A' specified
> multiple times; using first specification    Creating library
> build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\MapForm2A.cp35-win_amd64.lib and
> object build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\MapForm2A.cp35-win_amd64.exp
> Generating code c:\temp\mapform\mapform2a.c(7545) : fatal error C1002:
> compiler is out of heap space in pass 2 LINK : fatal error LNK1257:
> code generation failed error: command 'C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe'
> failed with exit status 1257

I can only add that the process gets stuck on the "Generating code" message for about 90 seconds before raising the C1002 exception.

The setup file is rather standard:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("MapForm2A.py")
)
```

The module is pure PyQt5 (pyuic5 output) with no other dependencies and works fine if interpreted directly with no Cython.

**EDIT: SOLUTION (Maybe someone will need it).**
Thanks to @DavidW (discussion in the comments below).

Setup.py has to be modified in the following way:

```
from distutils import _msvccompiler
_msvccompiler.PLAT_TO_VCVARS['win-amd64'] = 'amd64'

from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("MapForm2A.py"),
)
```

The first two lines force 64-bit toolchain.

Comment: Use 64bit toolchain: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3508173/5769463

Comment: @ead I think you're right but it looks like distutils works quite hard to force to the 32bit toolchain https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e488e300f5c01289c10906c2e53a8e43d6de32d8/Lib/distutils/_msvccompiler.py#L160

Comment: @BartM In the absence of other ideas you should probably just subdivide your script into smaller modules. Also be aware that this doesn't sound like the sort of thing that really benefits from Cython - maybe consider if it's worth the effort

Comment: It would help too see the whole log. It looks like the linker and not the compiler is failing. Disabling link time code generation could be enough.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've now edited the question to include the complete log.

Comment: You could try monkey-patching in setup.py: something like `from distutils import _msvccompiler; _msvcompiler.PLAT_TO_VCVARS['win-amd64'] = 'amd64_amd64'` (add it right at the top). I'm not in a position to test it, but it might work...

Comment: Ok, I tried it, and now my VS fails:     c:\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(68): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2     I am sure that set INCLUDE=... points to the right directories, io.h is there.

Comment: Possibly just `= 'amd64'` instead of `= 'amd64_amd64'`? If that doesn't work then I'm out of suggestions

Comment: IT WORKED. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if it's a good idea to work around the original problem, which is _heap space_ as the compiler tells us. I bet it is more an encapsulation issue than anything else. There should be a chance given to the garbage collector to fulfill it's purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the purposes of giving a little more explanation to something solved in the comments: the basic problem looks to be that you're compiling something large and complicated and MSVC has run out of memory at the linking step.

Microsoft has [a page about this error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1060?view=msvc-160) which suggests a number of options, with the main one being to use a 64-bit compiler. (Note that this is independent of whether you're compiling a 32-bit or 64-bit module - it's merely the choice of compiler executable)

When compiling Python extension modules (especially with setup.py) the compiler setup is typically selected by distutils. Unfortunately, it looks like distutils chooses to force a 32-bit compiler (see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e488e300f5c01289c10906c2e53a8e43d6de32d8/Lib/distutils/_msvccompiler.py#L160).

My suggestion was to dig into the distutils internals at the top of setup.py (before any real setup takes place) to override this setting

```
from distutils import _msvccompiler
_msvccompiler.PLAT_TO_VCVARS['win-amd64'] = 'amd64'
```

Essentially all you're really doing is passing the option `amd64` to the `vcvarsall.bat` script that microsoft supply to set up their compiler, thus getting a 64-bit compiler to build a 64-bit extension.