# Error while trying to build an executable from python files, using Cython and Visual Studio 2019 (32/64bits link.exe)

Tags: python, visual-studio, linker, cython, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to make an executable for win10, from python scripts : main.py, which import the module datatools.py

I created cythonizer.py (code below), to use cython to convert the .py files into .c and .pyd files

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Compiler import Options


ext_modules = [
            Extension("datatools",  ["datatools.py"]),
            Extension("main",  ["main.py"]),
        ]

for e in ext_modules:
    e.cython_directives = {'language_level': "3"}
    
Options.docstings = False 
Options.embed = "main" 

setup(
        cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
        ext_modules = ext_modules
    )
```

Then, on my win10 computer having visual studio 2019 community, I run the following commands in a "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS2019" :

```
python cythonizer.py build_ext --inplace
cl.exe /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\mme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -IC:\Users\mme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\PC datatools.c main.c /link /OUT:"myApp.exe" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MACHINE:X64 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\mpa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\mpa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\PCbuild
```

This process used to work, I was able to produce a working .exe
As I developped the thingy, datatools.py and main.py became heavier. Notabilly datatools.py now contains large dictionaries and lists.

Now, when I run the first command I get the Error (French OS sorry) :

```
LINK : l'éditeur de liens 32 bits (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe) manque d'espace de tas et va redémarrer l'édition des liens avec un éditeur de liens 64 bits

LINK : redémarrage de l'édition des liens avec l'éditeur de liens 64 bits 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe'

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: impossible d'ouvrir le fichier 'C:\Users\mme\Documents\aircraft2020-v0.26\datatools.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'

error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104
```

in other words:

- link.exe fails in 32 bits because it is lacking space during its link editing process and launches the 64 bits version instead
- in 64 bits it fails with fatal error LNK1104 : cannot open the .py file

I am guessing that it used to work because the 32 bit linker used to be enough. Now that datatool.py is too heavy, the 32 bits linker fails, then the 64 bits linker is launched but this one find the file locked because the 32bit one has opened it, so it fails as it cannot edit it.

Could this diagnostic be correct, and if yes, is there something I can put in my cythonizer.py files that instructs to use the 64 bits linker immediatly instead?

Comment: It's possible [this question/answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65197248/cythonize-ends-with-fatal-error-c1002-compiler-is-out-of-heap-space-in-pass-2/65206777#65206777) - it isn't exactly the same error message but I wonder if the solution would be similar

Answer (score 0):

I confirm my diagnostic was right, splitting the file in multiple lighter files was possible to avoid the problem.

Then, DavidW's suggestion (above) was also right, adding the following line in the cythoniser script solved the issue.

```
from distutils import _msvccompiler
_msvccompiler.PLAT_TO_VCVARS['win-amd64'] = 'amd64'
```